# "ValueError: Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass'). Got 'unknown' instead." in dataset kfold split

Tags: python, deep-learning, data-science, valueerror, k-fold

I have encountered  this error

```
"ValueError: Supported target types are: ('binary', 'multiclass'). Got 'unknown' instead."
```

while running this python code line 5

```
1    print(data.datasetsNames)
2    for dataset in data.datasetsNames:
3       X, Y, dictActivities = data.getData(dataset)
4
5       for train, test in kfold.split(X, Y):
.
.
.
.
10 def getData(datasetName):
11    X = np.load('./npy/' + datasetName + '-x.npy')
12    Y = np.load('./npy/' + datasetName + '-y.npy')
13    dictActivities = np.load('./npy/' + datasetName + '-labels.npy').item()
14   return X, Y, dictActivities
```

Y is output of getdata function and the result is a 1d array which its variables is in range 0 to 6.
Y=[1,2,5,0,0,0,6]

I checked with the bellow code the target type for X and Y:

X was `multiclass-multioutput`
Y was `unknown`.

```
from sklearn.utils.multiclass import type_of_target

print(type_of_target(X))
print(type_of_target(Y))
```

I read somewhere that the label_encoder can solve the error but I could not to solve it.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
y = label_encoder.fit_transform(target_labels)
```

any help please.....Thanks

The src code is hear : https://github.com/danielelic/deep-casas/blob/master/train.py

Comment: Can you point out where exactly your `y` data lives? Are you sure it's all integers 0 to 6? Can you trace through the steps in `type_of_target` to see where it goes wrong?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the first comment says, you need to figure out what type Y is. I downloaded the referenced code from github, ran portions of it, and it turns out Y is of type <class 'int'>. Apparently that is not supported by current versions of sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold, which is what your kfold object is. The following will allow you to proceed. Add the statement `Y = np.array(Y, dtype=np.int)` after your getdata() call, and the error should go away.